# How to properly get an IPAddress IPv6 or IPv4 now as of 2023?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipv6, ipv4

Is anybody else noticing that "http_x_forwarded_for" or "REMOTE_ADDR" returns a Private- "IPV6" value that is no longer useful?  I have had the same code for years, but all of a sudden I started receiving an error: "Exception message: Data too long for column 'ipaddress' at row 1"

After extending the column and having the customer try it again, I was able to determine what was happening.  I think this might be apart of some fundamental change in how IP works.  I'm not entirely sure.

The function below is for logging their IPAddress in my Database after the person logs into the website.

This is my current code that uses a two-fold approach:

```
protected string GetIPAddress()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

The problem is, I may get a IPv6 address and I look it up.  'Warning: .... is a private address', and sites will not even bother to tell me so much of what state they think they reside in, let alone what country.  In looking at the log on the server, I do have a IPv4 address for the same entry.

How do I correct this to be more accurate?  I know there is no such thing in IP-land as real, but there can be better.  Should I switch to IPv6?  In the past all of my DB records have been in IPv4.

Comment: The actual values come from the wire (for example, reverse proxy). So, making an assumption that they are IPv4 only is a risk. Also if you want to limit the scope of the values you should go and configure elsewhere, not on ASP.NET. You didn't show what you exactly want to achieve here, so you'd better edit the question and share more code.

Comment: I'm not understanding your comment too well.  'values from the wire...'?! Not on ASP.NET, not getting that either, because the scope of the question is for ASP.NET, if that was not clear.  The user is a web user, and I wish to record his IP after login.

Comment: You can't just get request with ipv6 as source ip address our of nowhere. That means you have ipv6 address on your server and you are accepting connections on it, in which case that should not be surprising.

Comment: Commonly the actual wire-up is `browser -> reverse proxy (like nginx) -> ASP.NET`, and headers like `X-Forwarded-For` are set by the reverse proxy (what I meant by "from the wire"). So, the values are not controlled by ASP.NET.

Comment: I've never seen the function above return a IPv6 address until very recently.  Like something has changed on 1/1/2023?  This is the reason for the question!

Comment: @Evk the IPv6 address can come from HTTP headers, not source IP address at IP layer if you check the source code.

Comment: @LexLi but here we use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, so some reverse proxy set this header, and where did it get the value from? It cannot trust any headers to get request ip address, since you can set headers to anything.

Comment: @Evk then it depends on which reverse proxy is being used and its internal logic. No assumption can be made so far without that critical information. Misconfiguration of a reverse proxy is commonly observed.

Comment: With that I can agree yes. I was assuming correctly configured proxy.

Comment: You mean some odd particular Browser or odd particular user.  Yes at first I blamed one user.  Yes, there is a one customer that seems to trigger this, that uses a peculiar ISP with a VPN.  But doesn't that mean it will happen in the future more and more?

Comment: The point is - if you have correctly configured reverse proxy who sets that HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR - it cannot contain ipv6 ip address unless you also have ipv6 address configured on your server and accepting connections on it. And in this case you should have known that it's possible to get such request.

Comment: I have made no new server configurations.  I searched the Event-Viewer, the first time the cited error occurs is 1/4/2023 (for the said particular one user).  I mean that's only time I've ever seen the error.  I tried to dissect your comment in the light of IIS 10.  Under Application Request Routing: Server Proxy Settings: It is set to Pass through.  'Reverse rewrite' is not checked.  I'm not even sure if this is what is meant.